# Advice on getting a stable analog reading of capacitance

Tags: arduino, capacitance

I would like to detect the presence of a person's hand in a project.

I am aware that one can use a capacitive touch system to do this. I have used a TTP223 module in the past and this works great for switches (it gives a digital output) but I would like to get an analog reading which tells me the proximity of the hand.

I have experimented doing this with an [arduino library](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CapacitiveSensor/) but the readings are quite unstable.

Are there any dedicated ICs which give a stable analog output of capacitance or approaches which could achieve this?

Comment: You need to tell us a lot more about the environment. For proximity sensing of a hand, capacitive measuring would not be my first choice. Ultrasonic springs to mind.

Comment: Theremin springs to mind.

Comment: what sensor did the theremin use? - environment would be relatively stable. indoors, on a table for instance. possibly battery powered which i know can create grounding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacitance sensing may not be the easiest option. The measured capacitance may depend on things other then the distance to the hand. Ultrasonic sensors might be a better choice.

That said, if you do want to go down the capacitance route, you probably want a *Capacitance to digital converter*. An example would be the Analog Devices AD7745 or AD7747. Both are based on the same delta-sigma core, but the former measures the capacitance between two plates, and the latter measures capacitance to ground. Other makes and models also exist.

Comment: thanks for that. id rather use capacitance because i can create an array of sensors and they can be small, ultrasonic sensors are quite bulky. would the chips you suggested give me an analogue output?

Comment: These chips give a 24-bit digital output code over an I2C interface. If you need a real analogue output, you could hook them up to a microcontroller and a DAC.

Comment: great, i think capacitive to digital was the tidbit of info i needed there. thanks very much.